# Apply Firefox policies.json only to Firefox but not to Nightly

Tags: firefox

I manage Firefox settings under Linux with a file policies.json placed in `/etc/firefox/policies`.

I now also installed Firefox Nightly on the same machine. It also seems to use the policies.json file.

Is it possible to make the policies.json directives apply only to Firefox but not to Firefox Nightly? How?